# Table 4 col 6 rows JSON format Quick Replies

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My task is to build a table in 4 columns and 6 lines of quick replies buttons. Messenger api allows display 11 quick replies in 1 line. 
Is it possible to build answers in several rows?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to check the [Quick Reply docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/quick-replies/) first: first of all it's 13 max not 11, but most importantly Quick Replies aren't permanent and disappear after the next message and therefore you cannot have multiple "rows" of Quick Replies.

Comment: My task is to place more buttons into one page. After selecting the remaining buttons should disappear. How do I place buttons in several rows ?

Comment: Like mentioned this isn't possible because Quick Replies aren't permanent and disappear after the next message and the QR limit is 13, so you cannot display 2 "rows" of Quick Replies